# "Fatal error during installation." SP1 VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, servicepacks

I'm facing this issue since past week and tried various solutions I found on the internet. None of those worked. So here's to my last resort.

Whenever I try to install SP1 for VS 2010 I get this error. I even tried installing it using ISO file but result's the same.

Here's the log file content:

```
OS Version = 6.1.7601, Platform 2, Service Pack 1
OS Description = Windows 7 - x64 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1
CommandLine = "G:\Setup.exe" 
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1
Package Version = 10.0.40219
User Experience Data Collection Policy: UserControlled
Number of applicable items: 11
Summary Information:

SetupUtility
Service Pack 1 Package
WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1
Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools SP1 - ENU
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 IntelliTrace Collection (x64)
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools
Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition
VSTO 4.0 Runtime x64
Visual Studio Tools for Office
Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools

Exe (G:\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
MSI (G:\VS10sp1_x86.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft     Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20150303_120544506-MSI_VS10sp1_x86.msi.txt
MSI (G:\RiaServices.msi) Installation failed. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual     Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20150303_120544506-    MSI_RiaServices.msi.txt
MSI (G:\VS10sp1_x86.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual     Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20150303_120544506-    MSI_VS10sp1_x86.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:01:47).
```

Comment: Anyone who answers this question is simply taking a guess - that error code is a generic one. You'll have to provide far more details if you want a definitive answer.

Comment: Also, anyone voting to close this as *Off topic - belongs on Super User* has arguably got it wrong - questions about installing Visual Studio are on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/57de87cb-607f-4c49-baa3-128eb0fbebfd/vs2010-sp1-installation-failed-with-error-code-0x80070643-fatal-error-during-installation?forum=vssetup

Actually, everything that has been posted here did not work at all for me. The issue got quickly solved by adding the "WOW64=DWORD(0)" value to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\msiserver

This solved the problem on my x64 Win7. How MS can screw something like this up, is beyond me.

Comment: Still same. I added "WOW64=DWORD(0)" as REG_DWORD value to msiserver if that's what you meant.

Comment: yeah i did. I don't know where things are going wrong!

Comment: Have you tried to run a repair on the original installation (non-sp)?

Comment: I ended up deleting and installing everything (including windows). But I think the issue was occurring due to Microsoft SQL Server which I installed before installing VS 2010.

Comment: I have the same.  Installed VS2013 and ended up with some small issues.  You are just never really sure in which order the SP's and the prerequisite software levels must be.  You need to install it in the "original timeline" method with updates only afterwards - or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Windows 7 and Linux on the same PC? if yes, then you might run into an odd error when you try to install Windows 7 Service Pack 1.

The reason for the error is a check that the service pack installer performs. When it determines that the active partition is not able to start Windows directly, it produces the error message.

The fix is to use **Windows Disk Management** to set the System Reserved partition as active; if there's no System Reserved partition, set the Windows volume as active.

After this fix is made, you should be able to run the SP1 installer.

For More Detail [Quick fix for Windows 7 SP1 installation errors](http://www.zdnet.com/article/quick-fix-for-windows-7-sp1-installation-errors/)

Answer (score 0):

Source: [Visual Studio 2010 SP1: Install Did Not Succeed; Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643](http://www.datazx.cn/Forums/en-US/6c54403c-1c88-4b82-8d1b-d0083a28d97b/action?threadDisplayName=visual-studio-2010-sp1-install-did-not-succeed-installation-failed-with-error-code-0x80070643&forum=vssetup)

I recommend you follow some steps below to install:

1. Remove Sp1 from control panel, to know if there are any files remained. Look into vslogs.cab\msiinv, use   Ctrl+F to search for Visual Studio 2010 Service Package 1
2. Remove Visual Studio completely with this tool:
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2010/08/23/visual-studio-2010-uninstall-utility.aspx
   If you have no previous VS installed,you can use the third command: Complete
   (VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx) Just drag the tool to
   Start>>Run then add the command /full /netfx    This step can help
   if you want to remove all components
3. Do fresh install of your products.

I hope this will help you cope with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error while installing SP1 from [downloaded ISO](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710) for VS 2010. As indicated in the log that you have mentioned, it was failing while installing **RiaServices.msi**. So to further investigate this, I tried installing RiaServices.msi alone and it failed with the error saying "Microsoft Silverlight 4 Developer Runtime not installed". I installed [Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18149) which includes Silverlight 4 developer runtime and tried installing SP1 again and it worked without any problem.

Hence to summarize, if anyone gets the error mentioned above while installing SP1, then make sure to install Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010 and try installing SP1 again.

Comment: I ended up deleting and installing everything (including partitions and windows). But I think the issue was occurring due to Microsoft SQL Manage Studio which I had installed before installing VS 2010.